# iphone development in php

Tags: php, iphone, mobile

Looking at developing an iphone app for the first time upon Windows.

I have found a few sdk's (such as Airplay) that allow me to do this but the majority require knowledge of C/C+

Does anyone know of anything similar that enables you to use PHP as the language?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build a web applications for the iPhone in PHP. Apple supports javascript api's for Mobile Safari which allow you get gain access to some iPhone specific functionality through javascript. The main pages of the application can be served from php and then any dynamic interaction can be handled with javascript. You're never going to achieve the same experience with this method vs actually using Objective-C though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing a (native) iPhone app, will writing a WebApp also be sufficient? That could be done in combination with PHP. Otherwise, your best chance is learning Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

go on http://www.phonegap.com/start/ 
you can even access hardware through javascript. Means you will use PHP to generate html/css/javascripts
but Definitely, you need Apple computer, developer certificate ($99 atleast), XCode (4 gb) .

but web app is web-app , it will be slower than real native app.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can develop a native iPhone application using PHP, HTML, CSS and Javascript. try [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) , but as wewals said You're never going to achieve the same experience with this method vs actually using Objective-C. consider learning objective-c for developing native iPhone application. you can as well as use HTML5, as iPhone's browser support HTML5 you can get a lot more functionality.